# Django Rest Framework viewsets queryset duplicate

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Can I use same query set for two different `ModelViewSet` classes?

I try to use the same queryset, but django rest framework duplicate my API route.

*views.py*

```
class PlannerAgentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = EstateStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlannerAgentListingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    http_method_names = ['get']

class PlannerClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = EstateStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlannerClientListingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

*urls.py*

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'planner_agent', views.PlannerAgentViewSet)
router.register(r'planner_client', views.PlannerClientViewSet)
```

And I obtain:

> "planner_agent": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/planner_client/",
>
> "planner_client": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/planner_client/",

When I use different queryset works. So I can use same queryset?
Thanks for helping.

**UPDATE:**
Route ***"http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/planner_agent/"*** exists but must accessed manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do it, but you have to manually set the `base_name` for your routes to change those uris.

In your case :

```
router.register(r'planner_agent', views.PlannerAgentViewSet, base_name='planner_agent')
router.register(r'planner_client', views.PlannerClientViewSet, base_name='planner_client')
```